# is there a good parser for rfc822 formatted email address

Tags: c#, parsing, mailkit, rfc822

usually, these emails come in the form name. I am trying to use **MailBoxAddress.Parse** to take the name and email address. I am getting too many errors here as it seems that people put their name in any format they want. For example, the following triggers an error:

```
Alert: xyz's Weather Now - West Association <emailxx@insignificantstylise.com>
Auto Insurance @ full-auto-coverage.com <emailxx@bigwigfeast.com>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing this:

```
static MailboxAddress ParseAddr (string input)
{
    int lt = input.IndexOf ('<');

    if (lt == -1)
        throw new FormatException ("Invalid address format");

    int gt = input.IndexOf ('>', lt);

    if (gt == -1)
        throw new FormatException ("Invalid address format");

    var name = input.Substring (0, lt).TrimEnd ();
    var addr = input.Substring (lt + 1, gt - (lt + 1));

    return new MailboxAddress (name, addr);
}
```